# "Deep Noether's Theorem": Building in Symmetry Constraints

Tags: machine-learning

If I have a learning problem that should have an inherent symmetry, is there a way to subject my learning problem to a symmetry constraint to enhance learning?

For example, if I am doing image recognition, I might want 2D rotational symmetry. Meaning that the rotated version of an image should get the same result as the original.

Or if I am learning to play tic-tac-toe, then rotating by 90deg should yield the same game play.

Has any research been done on this?

Comment: Yes, some; e.g., [Group Equivariant Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07576) ([code](https://github.com/tscohen/GrouPy)), [Harmonic Networks: Deep Translation and Rotation Equivariance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04642), [Deep Rotation Equivariant Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08623), [Exploiting Cyclic Symmetry in Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02660) etc. You just don't see it much in the wild yet.

Comment: @Emre Thanks! Do you know of any work down outside of CNN's?

Comment: No, I only have superficial knowledge of this niche. Notwithstanding, CNNs seem like a natural setting ...

Comment: I should also mention Risi Kondor's PhD dissertation, [Group theoretical methods in machine learning](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~risi/papers/KondorThesis.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: Take a look also at [Deep Symmetry Networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5424-deep-symmetry-networks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is just the study of [Invariant Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_theory) applied to Machine Learning

Answer (score 8):

From Emre's comment above, Section 4.4 of [Group theoretical methods in machine learning](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~risi/papers/KondorThesis.pdf) by Risi Kondor has detailed information and proofs about creating kernel methods that inherently have symmetries. I will summarize it in a hopefully intuitive way (I am a physicist not a mathematician!).

Most ML algorithms have a matrix multiplication like,
\begin{align}
s_i &= \sum_j W_{ij}~x_j \\
  &= \sum_j W_{ij}~(\vec{e}_j \cdot \vec{x})
\end{align}
with  $ \vec{x} $ being the input and $ W_{ij} $ being the weights we wish to train.

### Kernel Method

Enter the realm of [kernel methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method) and let the algorithm handle input via,
\begin{align}
s_i &= \sum_j W_{ij}~k(e_j,~x)
\end{align}
where now we generalize to $ x, e_j \in \mathcal{X} $.

Consider a group $ G $ that acts on $ \mathcal{X} $ via $ x \rightarrow T_g(x) $ for $ g \in G $. A simple way to make our algorithm invariant under this group is to make a kernel,
\begin{align}
k^G(x, y) &= \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} k(x, T_g(y))
\end{align}
with $ k(x, y) = k(T_g(x), T_g(y)) $.

So,
\begin{align}
k^G(x, T_h(y)) &= \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} k(x, T_{gh}(y)) \\
  &= \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} k(x, T_{g}(y)) \\
  &= \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} k(T_{g}(x), y)
\end{align}

For $ k(x, y) = x \cdot y $ which works for all unitary representations,

\begin{align}
k^G(x, T_h(y)) &= \left[ \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} T_{g}(x) \right] \cdot y
\end{align}

Which offers a transformation matrix that can symmeterize the input into the algorithm.

### SO(2) Example

Actually just the group that maps to $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ rotations for simplicity.

Let us run linear regression on data $ (\vec{x}_i, y_i) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R} $ where we expect a rotational symmetry.

Our optimization problem becomes,
\begin{align}
\min_{W_{j}} &\sum_i \frac{1}{2} (y_i - \tilde{y}_i)^2 \\
\tilde{y}_i &= \sum_j W_{j} k_G(e_j, x_i) + b_i
\end{align}

The kernel $ k(x, y) = \| x - y \|^2 $ satisfies $ k(x, y) = k(T_g(x), T_g(y)) $. You could also use $ k(x, y) = x \cdot y $ and a variety of kernels.

Thus,
\begin{align}
k_G(e_j, x_i) &= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=1}^4 \| R(n\pi/2)~\vec{e}_j - \vec{x}_i \|^2 \\
  &= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=1}^4 ( \cos(n\pi/2) - \vec{x}_{i1} )^2 + ( \sin(n\pi/2) - \vec{x}_{i2} )^2 \\
  &= \frac{1}{4} \left[ 2 \vec{x}_{i1}^2 + 2 \vec{x}_{i2}^2 + (1 - \vec{x}_{i1} )^2 + (1 - \vec{x}_{i2} )^2 + (1 + \vec{x}_{i1} )^2 + (1 + \vec{x}_{i2} )^2 \right] \\
  &= \vec{x}_{i1}^2 + \vec{x}_{i2}^2 + 1
\end{align}

Note that we needn't sum over $ j $ because it is the same for both. So our problem becomes,
\begin{align}
\min_{W} &\sum_i \frac{1}{2} (y_i - \tilde{y}_i)^2 \\
\tilde{y}_i &= W \left[ \vec{x}_{i1}^2 + \vec{x}_{i2}^2 + 1 \right] + b_i
\end{align}

Which yields the expected spherical symmetry!

### Tic-Tac-Toe

Example code can be seen [here](https://github.com/aidan-plenert-macdonald/tictactoe/commit/b243bbb607201932c2b1bbc7ae61bac713bfab05). It shows how we can create a matrix that encodes the symmetry and use it. **Note** that this is really bad when I actually run it! Working with other kernels at the moment.

Comment: Good job, Aidan! If you have time, you can write a more detailed blog post. The community will be most interested.

Comment: Not sure what community you are referring to, but I started writing more. I wanted to find a way to estimate the optimal kernel given a set of data. So I optimized entropy on kernel space to intuitively get a new set of features that are symmetrically constrained and also maximally entropic (ie. informative). Now whether that it the right approach. I can't say. Just a warning, the math is a bit of a hack job right now and kind of straight out of stat mech. https://www.overleaf.com/read/kdfzdbyhpbbq

Comment: Is there any meaningful approach when the symmetry group is not known?

Comment: @leitasat How do you know it's symmetric if you don't know the group?

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald from the data. Let's say we have 1000 sets of 100 pictures each, and within each set there are pictures of one object from different viewpoints. Can any algorithm "learn the idea" of SO(3) symmetry and use it on previously unseen objects?

Comment: @leitasat Your picture thing may not be as symmetric as you like. Unless you are careful with the distance, angle, etc, this could be a very hard problem let alone trying to figure out an intuitive symmetry group. The rotating pictures is already not SO(3) even with the best camera positioning. Let alone poor photography. Otherwise, you could simply train an invertible function that learns the groups of images and invert it to generate the group actions.